# HTML text-overflow ellipsis detection. Again

Tags: javascript, css

There is an element that implements Label one line with a specified width. Everything that does not fit in a cropped, and placed at end of line dots.
The sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/raHEb/7/
Actually the problem is to recognize whether the text will fit completely into an element, or be truncated.
This example works fine in IE9, IE8, but not quite give an accurate result in FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera, it can be seen, if the window is an example of gradually begin to narrow, the text will be cut first, and only then will turn red. That is, possible that the text will be truncated, and the function defining it returns false.

The solution given by Christian Varga is not quite correct, seen in: http://jsfiddle.net/cgzW8/20/
Smoothly resize the window, narrowing it. In browsers: Opera, Chrome, Safari, IE7, FF field "text" will be cut immediately, and only then will turn red.